# calling the correct virtual method using member function pointer

Tags: c++, function, virtual

In the example below, where I tried to reduce the problem to its minimal, there are 4 classes **A,B,C,D.**, which form an inheritance hierarchy

When the program starts, an object d from class **D** is created and the **test** method of the **D** class is called. This method in turns calls the **caller** method of the **C** class. This method tries to use member function pointer to call the correct **f** method. In this case it should call the **f** method associated to class **D** but it calls the one associated to class **B**.

How come ?

```
class A {
    public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

class B : public A{
    public:
    virtual void f() { cout << "IN B" << endl;}   
};

class C : public B{
    public:
    virtual void f() { B::f(); cout << "IN C" << endl; }
    virtual void caller(){
        void (A::*cb)() = NULL;
        cb = &A::f;
        (this->*cb)();
    }
};

class D : public C{
    public:
    virtual void f() { C::f(); cout << "IN D" << endl; }
    void test(){
         caller();
    }
};

int main(){
    D d;
    d.test(); // Why does this prints only "IN B" 
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE** : The code actually works, the problem had nothing to due with the presented code and seemed to come from a version mismatch between the library providing class A,B,C and the one providing class D.

Comment: +1: Short, well-worded question with well-indented code.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce with g++, even after fixing the accessibility of things so that the code compiles. Which compiler and version?

Comment: Pretty much all compilers [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/yJL1f$46) are giving the output you expect. Maybe you are not really showing the real code you're testing? In fact, the code from the question required some change in order to make it compile

Comment: If you're using prints to debug your code, make sure to use setvbuf to remove line buffering so that whatever you are printing gets printed immediately instead of when stdout gets filled and the buffer gets flushed http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/setvbuf/

Answer (score 2):

You sure it prints only "IN B"? I compile it on MSVC2012, I got

```
IN B
IN C
IN D
```

What's more, your original code does not compile on VS2012, at least not before I add `public`: to every class. e.g.:

```
class C : public B{
public:  // <--- here
    virtual void f() { B::f(); cout << "IN C" << endl; }
    virtual void caller(){
        void (A::*cb)() = NULL;
        cb = &A::f;
        (this->*cb)();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It prints

```
IN B
IN C
IN D
```

So, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: You were right, I edited my answer. however, the question is wrong at least in gcc.

Comment: Yes then its sure the problem is somewhere else! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

it works. add `public:` declaration. also warning about different behavior of overloading and virtualisation. best approach is to use pointer or reference.

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

class B : public A{
    public:
    virtual void f() { std::cout << "IN B" << std::endl;}   
};

class C : public B{
    public:
    virtual void f() { B::f(); std::cout << "IN C" << std::endl; }
    virtual void caller(){
        void (A::*cb)() = NULL;
        cb = &A::f;
        (this->*cb)();
    }
};

class D : public C{
    public:
    virtual void f() { C::f(); std::cout << "IN D" << std::endl; }
    void test(){
         caller();
    }
};
```

output:

> IN B
>   IN C
>   IN D